# Is there a way to use a shared database with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build my first app using PhoneGap, and I need to store info that app users can share and edit.

My app is intended to manage a team membership, attendance to meetings, topics discussed in meetings, etc., and I need more than 1 people to be able to view and update this info.

I'm aware of the documentation suggesting to use SQL Lite (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) but that's a local solution.

Is there a way to get users to share info? Preferrably for free ;)
Thanks!

Comment: really! Did you think about simply saving shared data on live server and share data across  all applications?? like save data in mysql or SQL database in your web hosting and access them as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to share data you might want to create an API and have your PhoneGap App fetch and store data thru that API. Or you might want to take a look at [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) or [kii.com](http://www.kii.com).